# Swagger params names form data

Tags: go, swagger

I am trying to create documentation for my API (golang)

```
// swagger:parameters getTax
type TaxQS struct {
    // Required: true
    TaxCode string `form:"tax_code" binding:"required"`
    // birth place
    Place string `form:"model"`
    // year 
    Year int `form:"year"`
    // month
    Month int `form:"month"`
```

for requests I use query params and swagger works fine I have the doc for my API but the only problem is param names are different for example I was expected param name is `tax_code` but I have `TaxCode` also I try to add `// in: query` still I have this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try generating swagger doc after adding `json` tag in your struct

```golang
// swagger:parameters getTax
type TaxQS struct {
    // Required: true
    TaxCode string `json:"tax_code" form:"tax_code" binding:"required"`
    // birth place
    Place string `json:"model" form:"model"`
    // year 
    Year int `json:"year" form:"year"`
    // month
    Month int `json:"month" form:"month"`
}
```